# Set form field to valid Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have an app that has an address form

The user can either have a UK or non UK address

The fields have validators set up in an external file, all works fine, however

When the user swaps between UK or non UK address postcode is no longer required I can remove validators

```
this.paymentForm.get('postcode').setValidators(null);
this.paymentForm.get('postcode').setErrors({'valid': true});
this.paymentForm.get('postcode').markAsPristine()
this.paymentForm.get('postcode').markAsUntouched();
```

But the field valid property always shows as valid: false

Have tried

```
this.paymentForm.get('postcode').setErrors({'valid': true});
```

But nothing seems to work

Comment: So what's the problem? You just said that if postcode is not required, you will remove validators and it is normal to be shown as valid. If it is the other way around, from non-UK to UK, then you need to apply UK postcode validation and run `.updateValueAndValidity()`.

Comment: Sorry just updated question the valid property is always false

Comment: You are only clearing async validators. Do you have, by any chance non-async validators like `Validators.required`?

Comment: Yes, thank you, you were right, but I'm still getting the same result

Comment: try using `.clearValidators()` instead of `.setValidators(null)`. Also, I am not sure that `.setErrors()` is worth it. Call `clearValidators()` and then call `updateValueAndValidity()`. I think this should be enough.

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it works, please select it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Best option here is calling `.setErrors(null)` on the `FormControl`**

So you can do this as follows:

Get your `FormControl` like this: `this.paymentForm.get('postcode')`

And mark it as valid like this: `this.paymentForm.get('postcode').setErrors(null);`